# How to correctly access properties of a Sencha model?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

There appear to be a number of different ways how to access properties of a Sencha (Touch) model. However, I don't seem to be able to find proper documentation of which is the "correct" way of doing it.

**Model creation**

```
var model = Ext.create('MyApp.model.MyModel', {
  name: value,
  foo: bar,
  ...
})
```

**Property access**

- `model.get('name')` or `model.set('name', newValue)`
- `model.data.name` or `model.data.name = newValue`
- `model.raw.name` seems to always return a string no matter what the data type in the model definition is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's sort this all out:

- `get` and `set` methods are the intended accessors for model field values.
- `model.data` is the object that stores the client side model value, that is that have been converted from the data received from the <strike>server</strike> proxy using the fields configuration  (type, convert method, etc.).
- `model.raw` is the raw data that was received from the <strike>server</strike> proxy, before it was converted to <strike>client side</strike> application domain model values. You should avoid using it, or you will tie yourself to your proxy/server.
- `model['name']`: as you've said, it doesn't work. Don't hope for it to come back (I don't even really understand that it worked at one point).

Now, which one should you use? Clearly, the last two ones are already out of the match.

The `model.data` object should give you the expected result in *most* cases (see bellow), and should give you a marginal performance gain other calling a function.

However, IMO you should always prefer to use the getters and setters, for two reasons.

First, it might happen that someone in your team (or you from the past) decides that the getter/setter is a good point to add some custom logic.  In this case, bypassing the accessor by using the  `data` object directly will also bypass this logic, and yield unpredictable result.

Secondly, getters and setters make it really easier to debug some situations, by making it easy to know from where modifications of the model values are coming. I mean, if one day you were to ask yourself "f**k, why is my model field value changing to this??". If all the code uses the getters, you'll just have to put a breakpoint in there, and you'll catch the culprit hand in bag. On the other hand, if the incriminated code uses the `data` object directly, you'll be stuck to do a whole project search for... You can't tell exactly what... `data.name =`? `data['name'] =`? `name:`? etc.

Now that I think about it, there is yet another reason. A [deprecated](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-persistenceProperty) one apparently. But the `data` object name used to be customizable using this `persistenceProperty` option. So, in some cases, the `data` object won't even be available, and code doing `model.data.name` instead of `model[model.persistenceProperty].name` would crash, plain and simple.

Short answer: use the accessors.

Comment: "...someone in your team decides that the getter/setter is a good point to add some custom logic" - then someone would have a serious problem we me. A getter/setter with side effects is inacceptable. A getter that does more than just return the value *as is* is not a getter and shouldn't be called such. But of course, if someone disagrees with could argue for hours.

Comment: That's probably a good policy for getters, but setters are often used to normalize value, or update the internal state of the object according to the new value. In the precise case of Ext models, setters will update the dirty state of the field, for example.